# QLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation

Tags: sql, laravel, integrity

All of a sudden a site that i manage started giving this error whenever we try to add a new event.
This did not happen before and nothing was changed on the server front or the coding.

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'home_image' cannot be null in /home/xxx/laravel-app/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php on line 729
```

While updating content, all fields were entered properly and none were left null.

Can someone help what could be causing this issue?

Comment: check your code properly, you are sending `null` as a value for `home_image` from your code anywhere

Comment: could you put your code here so people can help you?

Comment: Use `NULL` as default attribute for this column in your table.

Comment: The line 729 only has this.

catch (Exception $e) {
            throw new QueryException(
                $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
            );
        }

Comment: The website was working fine with notnull attribute. I uploaded content 2 weeks ago also, but now when i try to add a new event, it's giving this error :(

Answer (score 0):

Somehow image name is not added in **home_image** field in a database. Either set it default **NULL** or you have to set required validation for **home_image** field.

Comment: But it was all working fine until 2 weeks ago. No changes were made to the code.

Comment: Have you checked permission of folder where image is uploading

Comment: Yes. The folder has a 775 permission

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is magic, try catch the code which are responsible of the insertion in database and log the data used when an exception is thrown.
Check your logs and you will have more information to debug.